# #!bin/sh call program in centOS bad command startup

Tags: bash, centos, postfix-mta

Works fine in Debian:

```
#!/bin/sh

time /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp $@
```

in CentOS getting error in mail logs:

```
warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp_time pid 28456 exit status 1
warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp_time: bad command startup -- throttling
```

debuggin error `exec 2>>/tmp/smtp.log; set -x; time /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp "$@"`

```
+ time /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp -n smtptime -t unix -u -c
which: no /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp in ((null))
ERROR: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp cannot be found.
```

But file exist and have r+x rights.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but `$@` is buggy -- it string-splits and glob-expands your arguments. Use `"$@"` instead.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy for answer, it doesn't makes changes.

Comment: Anyhow, "bad command startup" doesn't really tell us anything useful here -- it says that the command exited quickly, so postfix is deciding not to run it (very often) anymore, but that has nothing useful to tell us about **why** it exited quickly.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't change your immediate behavior, that's why I said "not your immediate problem", and added this as a comment rather than an answer. It certainly *would* make a difference if you were trying to pass command-line arguments with spaces, though.

Comment: ...what I would suggest is logging/tracing your results. `exec 2>>/tmp/smtp.log; set -x; time /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp "$@"` will create a `/tmp/smtp.log` that tells us what your arguments are, and includes any stderr that `smtp` emits (which is likely to be helpful).

Comment: thank you @CharlesDuffy now i have more information it gives following error: + time /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp -n smtptime -t unix -u -c
which: no /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp in ((null))
ERROR: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp cannot be found.

Comment: Well, there's your answer -- it's pretty clear on its face, isn't it?

Comment: You can't assume that files will be installed in the same place between different Linux distributions (and also shouldn't assume that daemons will have any particular value for PATH).

Comment: no, its not, file exist and have r+x rights for all

Comment: yes, in debian was /usr/lib/postfix, but in centos i've modifed to right path /usr/libexec/postfix

Comment: There's also security policy and labeling to deal with. If SELinux or a chroot environment is limiting filesystem access, you've got those to deal with as well.

Comment: anyhow, though, when I talk about `PATH`, I mean the environment variable by that name. It looks like it's not set. If you put an `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/libexec/postfix` at the top of your script, that may have some useful effect.

Comment: this also looks like the external `time` invocation in use on this system expects to do a PATH lookup instead of being given a fully-qualified directory name -- so you may need to add an explicit PATH including `/usr/libexec/postfix` as above, and then run `time smtp "$@"`

Comment: export also hasn't makes any changes :( thank you @CharlesDuffy i've updated the question with additional debugging info. Very useful method

Comment: BTW, have you tried removing `time`, to determine whether this works without it?

Comment: Ohh, yes, @CharlesDuffy Right! problem was not the script.. the error is somewhere completely different place `fatal: unknown service: smtp/tcp`

Comment: You might delete the question yourself, if its resolution is such that it doesn't have an answer that will be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

From your `set -x` logging, it looks like the implementation of `time` used by your `/bin/sh` tries to locate the file to run with `which`, without looking at whether that file is already specified as a fully-qualified PATH. Thus, consider:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/libexec/postfix:/bin:/usr/bin
time smtp "$@"
```

Comment: now error shows same data but not about smtp, but about this calling script smtp_time `warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp_time: bad command startup -- throttling`

Comment: Thank you very much @Charles now i have more info about error, and where to search it.